# C++ dll function using std:string

Tags: c++, dllimport

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [std::string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874551/stdstring-in-c)
>   [How can I call a function of a C++ DLL that accepts a parameter of type stringstream from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538562/how-can-i-call-a-function-of-a-c-dll-that-accepts-a-parameter-of-type-stringst)

Is there a way to convert from a c++ std:string to C# System.String? I'm calling a function from a C++ dll that takes a std:string as input. Is there a simple way to do this?

C#:

```
[DllImport(@"MyDLL.dll")]
[return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
public static extern bool myFunction([In, Out]string input);
```

C++:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BOOL __stdcall myFunction(const std::string& input)
{
  //Code is here
}
```

Comment: Your DLL should not be using `std::string` in its interface. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538562/how-can-i-call-a-function-of-a-c-dll-that-accepts-a-parameter-of-type-stringst/4551798#4551798)

Comment: It is never a good idea to share builtin complex datatypes between different programming languages (no matter how similar), since you don't know how the datatype is built internally. A better way is to export something known to you, in this context a null-terminated char* should do the job.

Comment: Note that `BOOL` in C/C++ should be marshaled with the default marshaler, not as `UnmanagedType.I1` -- it is C++'s `bool` that must be marshaled as `I1` or `U1`.