# Call c++ dll class functions from other programming language

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I need to make gui application that must call c++ dll class functions. What programming languages are able to call class functions without problems? By problems I mean wrappers and similar things.

Comment: You cannot be sure even in case of C++ with same compiler but  different compiler options. So, if you're not 100% sure that your dynamic library and caller will be compiled with same compiler and same options, same STL implementation etc., and you're not looking for troubles, use good old `extern "C"` factory or [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model)-like things ;)

Comment: [Don't export C++ objects in a DLL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314101/creating-c-dll-without-static-methods/12314276#12314276)

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't make the GUI directly in c++?
[QT](http://qt.digia.com/) is a well known and mature framework, for instance

Answer (score 0):

C functions in a DLL can be called from most languages.

C++ functions, particularly with classes are difficult at best. Probably they will cause you more trouble than it is worth.

My advice is to just use C++ and prevent the problems.

If you insist on building your GUI with another language X, then your best approach would be to write a *glue* DLL, written in C++, that shows a C-only interface to the X-GUI and accesses the target C++ classes directly.